# The Grinder - Client opened connection but sent no bytes

Tags: http, load-testing, grinder

When attempting to use the TCPProxy tool included with The Grinder, I get the following error. I have accepted

```
3/10/11 10:47:58 AM (tcpproxy): Failed to determine proxy destination.

Client opened connection but sent no bytes.
```

I have my browser proxy settings at localhost and the right port. I realise you need more details, so let me know which in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Ensure you do not have a local antivirus which intercepts TCP connections
- Ensure your local firewall is not configured too strict
- Ensure you've set localhost:8001 as the *http* proxy in your browser, not socks
- Ensure your browser attempts to go to a real site, not the local proxy

Which browser on which OS? Any antivirus? Firewall? Are you connecting to a real non-SSL site? Do you normally use a proxy or directly connect?

Comment: Changed browser and it worked fine. Does not work in Chrome for whatever reason.